# Disabling Overlays appearing in a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to get screenshots for a set of urls using selenium, and many of them have overlays / frames appearing in the front, which i don't want as they hide the main content.

Some Examples : 
1. https://au.shein.com/style/Boho-sc-00100642.html?url_from=aubingsearch16_BohoCloth01_srsa_20200106
2. https://www.vacationrenter.com/search/Kingsland%2C%20TX%2C%20USA?placeId=ChIJE8AdnlX-WoYRL3_6YUNIJ4s&al=Kingsland&as=Vacation%20Rentals

Is there a generic way of disabling these type of overlays ?

Disabling javascript works, but it also removes images.

Comment: Not in a generic way, but there is "WebdriverEventListener": https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html  It has a beforeScreenshot listener: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html#beforeGetScreenshotAs-org.openqa.selenium.OutputType-

Comment: Why can't we check for the popup before taking the screenshot? If it's present close it, else go ahead and take the screenshot.

Comment: Can you try if this works for above URL I have posted ?